# Facebook - GraphApi from v1.0 to v2.0 : An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm working on an old facebook application and we had to migrate from graphApi v1 to v2.
I delete the publish_stream permission (no longer exists) but users cannot login to the application we have this error :

> An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

It still works for admin users... I don't understand what's happening

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/api-v1-deprecation

I guess you're requesting extended permissions, and did not go under the Login Review process:

> Require Login Review for all apps that use Facebook Login and ask people for permissions other than email, public_profile or user_friends. Any permissions that haven't been reviewed and approved will no longer show in the Login dialog and apps can't access, ask for, or be granted them.